# WebForm_DoCallBack is not a function

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

For my sharepoint 2010 When I am going to create a sitecollection I want to choose username
at that time i got this error "window.WebForm_DoCallBack is not a function" in firefox and in IE I got error that "WebForm_DoCallBack function is not defined". I got same error when I try to add list item.
      I can solve that error by reinstalling the sharepoint server but error occurs again after 2/3 days.
      This function is in init.js file.

I am searching for the solution on internet but no solution yet got.So please help me to find out the solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's a system file, it's pretty weird... make sure you, or anybody at work, are not deploying any "init.js" file within root layouts folder and retracting it. is this a test environment?

Comment: Thanks Gonzix for reply .. no one has deployed the init.js. Yes this is test environment.
Still stuck with the issue..